# GLSL <> operators on a vec4

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm looking at some newer GLSL code that doesn't compile to my current version of OpenGL and I'm wondering what the short form of the following means:

```
vec4 base;

if (base < 0.5) {
    result = (2.0 * base * blend);
}
```

Is this equivalent to:

```
if (base.r < 0.5 && base.g < 0.5 && base.b < 0.5 && base.a < 0.5) {
    result.r = 2.0 * base.r * blend.r;
    result.g = 2.0 * base.g * blend.g;
    result.b = 2.0 * base.b * blend.b;
    result.a = 2.0 * base.a * blend.a;
}
```

Edit:

```
Error:
Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
Wrong operand types no operation '<' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'highp 3-component vector of float' and a right operand of type 'const float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I've also tried:

```
(base.rgb < vec3(0.5))
... Wrong operand types no operation '<' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'highp 3-component vector of float' and a right operand of type 'const highp 3-component vector of float'
```

I'm assuming this is because I'm using GLSL 1.2.
ATI Radeon 3450

Comment: OS, GL implementation vendor, driver version, and error message(s)?

Comment: So the original code does not compile? Where did you get it from? Are you sure it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf), section 5.9 (top of page 38):

> The relational operators greater than
>   (>), less than (<), greater than or
>   equal (>=), and less than or equal
>   (<=) operate only on scalar integer
>   and scalar floating-point expressions.
>   The result is scalar Boolean. Either
>   the operands’ types must match, or the
>   conversions from Section 4.1.10
>   “Implicit Conversions” will be applied
>   to the integer operand, after which
>   the types must match. To do
>   component-wise relational comparisons
>   on vectors, use the built-in functions
>   lessThan, lessThanEqual, greaterThan,
>   and greaterThanEqual.

Looks like you want the **lessThan** function.  Check section 8.6 (page 62).

- [`lessThan()` - http://www.opengl.org/](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/lessThan.xhtml) (see also: [`all()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/all.xhtml))

Comment: Just a nitpick: a valid answer, but you might want to refer to http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.10.6.clean.pdf . Your spec is from 2006

Comment: @Bart: The OP said s/he was using GLSL 1.2, so I figured I would pull from that version of the spec.  Plus Mesa is still on 2.1 so 4.1 doesn't exist yet :)

Comment: :) And there I come with my nitpicking. Should have realized there was a reason. ;) Anyway, now the OP has 2 to choose from. :p