# GLSL - Overloaded Functions - Comparing Vec values

Tags: glsl

I'm trying to test colour values and change them if they're greater than 0.5.

I started out with this test which didn't compile:

```
    if(colourIn.b > 0.5){
       colourIn.b=0.0;
    }
```

I read through some post on here and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860033/glsl-operators-on-a-vec4) post which explains relational operators only work on scalar integer and scalar floating-point expressions.

So after finding out a good way to efficiently [test frag values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844547/glsl-test-fragment-values) and using the built in functions, changed it to:

```
    float mixValue = clamp(ceil(colourIn.b * 2.0) - 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    if(greaterThan(colourIn.b,0.5)){
       colourIn.b = mix(colourIn.b, 0.0, mixValue);}
```

Unfortunately it still doesn't compile; it gives the following errors:

```
    ERROR: 0:15 error(202) No matching overloaded function found greaterThan
    ERROR: 0:16 error(164) 1-value required assigned "colourIn" (can't modify an input)
    ERROR: 0:15 error(179) Boolean expression expected
```

For this I get that the greatThan function is being used wrong? (I can't find an example in similar circumstances) and that the colourIn value cannot be changed?

I may be wrong... Please help me figure this out.

Basically, I want to change any pixels with Blue values greater than 0.5 to white (0.0).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true that relational operators only work on scalars... what on Earth is `colourIn` declared as (`bvec`)? Considering boolean colors do not make a lot of sense, usually `colourIn.b` would be a scalar component from a `vecN` or `ivecN` type. Please include the actual body of the shader you are trying to compile.

Additionally, `greaterThan (...)` does not work on scalar types, only vector. What it returns is a boolean vector containing the result of the test v1 > v2 for each component in v1 and v2.

So for instance consider the following pseudo-code,

```c
vec3  v1 = vec3 (1,2,3);
vec3  v2 = vec3 (3,2,1);

bvec3 gt = greaterThan (v1, v2);
```

Then the boolean vector `gt` would have the following form:

```c
gt.x = false;
gt.y = false;
gt.z = true;
```

However, the biggest problem you have is you are trying to modify an input value. You cannot do this, fragment shader inputs are interpolated from vertex transform (vertex shader, geometry shader, tessellation shader) outputs during rasterization and are read-only. Vertex shader inputs are from your vertex buffer and are also read-only. The only thing shaders are capable of doing is computing the output for the next stage in the pipeline.

In a fragment shader, the next stage would be blending for final pixel output. In a vertex shader it would be tessellation (GL4+) and primitive assembly (geometry shader) and rasterization (fragment shader).

Comment: Oh I see! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for taking the time to explain it. So is it possible at all to change a single pixel value in a frag after testing it's input value? Or would it only be possible using the `mix` function and blend them? Thanks for explaining the boolean `greaterThan` function too; best explanation I've read this evening. Also colourIn is a `vec3` of RGB values... It's the B i'm trying to change to white if the value is over 0.5.... Thanks.

Comment: @Reanimation: In the simplest of fragment shaders, the output color is written to `gl_FragColor`. This is a `vec4`, so you can write a statement along the lines of: `gl_FragColor.b = ...` to set the blue channel to *anything* that you want. The input cannot be changed, but you can (and usually do) compute your output based on the input.